# How can We Get Live Emails to Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, live, live-sdk

I am trying to Get My live Emails to My wp App

Is it Possibly to get Emails into our App,
Now i am Getting Email Address and Date Of Birth and Some Other But Not getting Email's

My Xaml Code is Like this

```
<live:SignInButton ClientId="000000004C0FWD99" Scopes="wl.basic wl.offline_access wl.signin wl.contacts_birthday wl.emails" Branding="Windows" TextType="Login"  d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" SessionChanged="SignInButton_SessionChanged" />
```

C#

```
private void SignInButton_SessionChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Live.Controls.LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null && e.Session != null && e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            this.liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
            Session = e.Session;
            this.LoginIn();

        }
        else
            this.GetUserProfile();

    }

    private void GetUserProfile()
    {
        LiveConnectClient clientGetMe = new LiveConnectClient(Session);
        clientGetMe.GetCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(clientGetMe_GetCompleted);
        clientGetMe.GetAsync("me", null);

        LiveConnectClient clientGetPicture = new LiveConnectClient(Session);
        clientGetPicture.GetCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(clientGetPicture_GetCompleted);
        clientGetPicture.GetAsync("me/picture");

    }
```

How can I get Email's with with Subject, From Address and Mail Content

is it Possibly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Only interaction with contacts and calendars is possible.

> You can use the Live Connect APIs to do the following things in Hotmail:
>
> - Create new contacts, and read existing ones, in a user's contacts list.
> - Create, read, update, and delete a user's calendars and the calendars' associated events.
> - Subscribe a user to a public calendar, such as a list of holidays.
> - Use the friend finder feature to discover whether any of a users' contacts are also registered users of your website.

From: [Live SDK developer guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641.aspx#hotmail)